# Estimating $n$ column norms of $A$ by using less than $n$ calls to $Ax$?

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have an $?? \times n$ matrix $A$ that is only accessible through matrix-vector products $Ax$. These are expensive in my application, is there a way to approximate vector $x$ of $n$ column norms of $A$ by using less than $n$ calls to the matrix-vector product?

Exact calculation using $n$ calls for $n=3$

$$
\begin{aligned}a_{1}=A \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\a_{2}=A\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\a_{3}=A\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
x=\langle\left\| a_{1}\right\|,\left\| a_{2}\right\|,\left\| a_{3}\right\| \rangle\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: If this procedure existed, then it would also work for $n$, i.e., the task of computing the norm of a single vector. In general, there are no short-cut for this. Are there any restrictions on the matrix or the norm that can be exploited ? Is there any information available about the underlying application? Why are you limited to completing individual matrix vector operations one by one? Why are the operations actually slow? What sort of hardware are you using?

Comment: @CarlChristian you can estimate n row norm squared by using less than n calls to Ax by using Hutchinson estimator - sample standard normal x, in expectation they are the average values of squared entries of y=Ax

Comment: you could use Hutchison trace estimator to estimate the sum of any subset of rows. It seems conceivable that a smart choice of subsets smaller than n would allow recovering all n norms

Comment: Seems like principal component analysis or something similar might be useful here.  If you randomly throw vectors at $A$ and take the resulting norm, the largest variance will happen when you have large coefficients on the biggest norm columns of $A$.  You should then be able to estimate the largest norm columns of $A$.  Just a thought.  (I'm not enough of an expert to know how this would be best accomplished in detail.)